# Différentes prononciations du mot alcool

Tags: prononciation, anglicismes

Le gouvernement du Canada peut a priori sembler une bonne référence linguistique en français et en anglais. Il est mentionné sur [leur site](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_a&page=9YAm8Ba-uDUU.html) que la prononciation [alkoɔl] du mot *alcool* serait un anglicisme phonétique. Je n'en ai personnellement jamais remarqué d'autres jusqu'à ce qu'un jour de ma treizième année, un ami m'affirme péremptoirement que je me trompe et qu'il faut dire [alkɔl]. On vérifiera rapidement qu'il avait les dictionnaires de son côté, ainsi que l'opinion du gouvernement du Canada.

Cependant, comme je ne démords pas rapidement et que j'ai éventuellement lu Rabelais, qui m'a initié à la très dynamique mouvance du français oral, j'ai cherché à connaître l'ancien usage concernant la prononciation de ce mot. J'ai trouvé cette référence ([Traité complet de la prononciation française dans la seconde moitié du XIXe siècle](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Ht9FAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=prononciation%20fran%C3%A7aise%2019e%20si%C3%A8cle&source=bl&ots=8DGl4Vc5SA&sig=TcXZs3xHl1JaPOkigseMkx1xSJ8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAzL7Z19TSAhXh44MKHV8VAhIQ6AEIUjAH#v=twopage&q&f=false)), qui a selon moi l'avantage d'être contemporaine des prononciations qu'elle décrit. On y lit que la prononciation formelle au XIXe siècle serait [alkoɔl] (le transfert vers l'alphabet phonétique international est de moi), et que la langue familière supprime un o et dit [alkɔl].

Mes questions:

- Le *Traité complet de la prononciation française dans la seconde moitié du XIXe siècle* est-il une référence fiable?
- Doit-on considérer la prononciation [alkoɔl] comme un anglicisme, ou comme le vestige d'une prononciation ancienne, à la rigueur entretenue par la proximité de la langue anglaise dans l'histoire et la géographie du Canada francophone?
- Si l'anglicisme est rejeté dans la question précédente, la position du gouvernement du Canada peut-elle se justifier par une stratégie politique quelconque, ou serait-elle simplement mal informée?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En français de France, il semble ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/alcool)) que la prononciation disyllabique de *-cool* ait disparue au début du vingtième siècle, au profit de la prononciation monosyllabique, ce qui expliquerait la prononciation donnée dans le *Traité complet de la prononciation française dans la seconde moitié du XIXe siècle*.

Il n'est pas mentionné que la prononciation disyllabique serait un anglicisme, et je crois plutôt qu'elle serait ancienne. Le mot vient de l'Arabe par l'intermédiaire de l'Espagnol, et le mot Espagnol est *alcohol* venant de *kuḥúl*, qui était déjà disyllabique. La prononciation en Espagnol peut apparemment être soit monosyllabique, soit disyllabique, comme Luke le mentionne dans son commentaire ci-dessous.

Comment: The Spanish can be [either way](http://ow.ly/AHEf309UWcQ); I'm not sure if there's a regional/generational border. Interestingly, the Arabic *kuḥúl* itself [apparently](http://ow.ly/RXZh309UWfT) comes from the classical Arabic *kuḥl*, which is monosyllabic. It's a good example of how these things go: the 2nd syllable was presumably a harmonic epenthesis to break up a difficult consonant cluster; borrowed into Spanish, the middle consonant lenited till it disappeared, leaving two vowels; the hiatus between these two identical vowels is then resolved by deletion in other borrowing languages...

Comment: La fin de la réponse va au delà de l'anglicisme basique et entraîne le commentaire suivant. PS1: En espagnol, les deux o d'alcool se prononcent et s'écrivent distinctement: *alcohol* PS2: Je prononce souvent zoo « zoho » alors termiumplus semble indiquer que « zou » à l'anglaise est courant au Québec.

Comment: @jlliagre - corrigé. Le mot ne s'écrit-il pas _alcho**h**ol_ en espagnol?

Comment: It is, but *h* is not pronounced in Spanish. [This article](http://ow.ly/1zIS309UYNr) claims that it doesn't break up diphthongs (although I think of *zanahoria*... but supposedly Spanish phonology would demand a break in that hiatus anyway...) That article actually claims that alcohol ends in just one syllable, but that's probably too far a generalization. Linguistically, if we expect one to be the standard and the other a "common variation" then 2 syllables for *cool* would be the standard since you'd expect them to run into each other but you wouldn't expect one syllable to duplicate.

Comment: Curieusement, je croyais qu'il fallait un _h_ en français aussi, mais le dictionnaire n'a pas l'air d'accord. Je me demande où j'ai pris cette idée. Peut-être dans une classe de chimie...

Comment: @Frank Classe de chimie s'appuyant sur un très vieux livre alors. Alcohol étant en concurrence avec alcool jusque vers 1850.

Comment: @LukeSawczak En espagnol, j'ai entendu plusieurs prononciations, soit deux o, le deuxième étant accentué, soit un o allongé et accentué (à mon avis la plus courante mais je peux me tromper), soit un o accentué standard. La tendance est vers la simplification. C'est la même en italien: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/A/alcol-alcool.shtml?refresh_ce-cp

Comment: jlliagre, je serais plutôt en accord avec Termiumplus déclarant que « zou » est commun au Québec. Ça se trouve à être ma prononciation, mais aussi celle de plusieurs de ceux que j'entends prononcer ce mot.

Comment: « Zou » pour moi itou, mais pas dans _zoologie_ etc.